# Calcular média com resultado do Pivot

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, tabela-banco-de-dados, pivot

Tenho uma query que me retorna as notas de alunos em determinados testes. A quantidade de teste pode variar. Utilizo o comando Pivot para transformar os nomes dos testes em colunas e assim organizar  teste/nota, como mostra a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde "SENEM_01", "02", "03" são nomes de teste. O que eu preciso é calcular a média destes valores. Lembrando que a quantidade de teste pode variar.

Minha consulta está assim:

```
WITH  notas_testes as(
    SELECT 
    ft.inscricao,
    ft.nota_num,
    ft.idteste,
    a.nome,
    ft.unidade
    from [Easy395].[dbo].[aluno] a
    INNER JOIN [Easy395].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft
        ON a.inscricao = ft.inscricao   
)

select *
from notas_testes
PIVOT (SUM(nota_num) FOR idteste IN ([SENEM_01], [SENEM_02], [SENEM_03]))pvt
```

Answer (score 3):

O pivot é muito útil para mostrar a nota de todos testes em apenas uma linha, no entanto se o objetivo é ter um resultado semelhante, mas substituindo as 3 colunas de notas de testes por apenas 1 com a média final, o melhor será calcular o valor sem usar o pivot.

Tendo por base a query principal, e supondo que é para fazer uma média aritmética simples, fica:

```
SELECT  ft.inscricao,
        media = avg(ft.nota_num),
        --ft.idteste,
        a.nome,
        ft.unidade
from [Easy395].[dbo].[aluno] a
    INNER JOIN [Easy395].[dbo].[faz_teste] ft
        ON a.inscricao = ft.inscricao 
group by ft.inscricao, a.nome, ft.unidade
```

Aqui pode ainda haver um problema (supondo que a tabela [faz_teste] tem apenas os testes respondidos e não todos os que poderão ser respondidos):
Os testes sem nota contam para a média?

- Se não contam. Tudo ok.
- Se contam, deve ser feito o left join com a tabela [faz_teste] e adicionado um relacionamento com a tabela que tem os testes disponíveis. Assim, a linha *media = avg(ft.nota_num)* deve ser alterada para *media = avg(isnull(ft.nota_num,0))*, e passarão a contar com valor=0.